# How to transform an array / order of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects that I'm trying to transform into a new array. I'm only trying to rearrange the structure of the data, but am unfortunately not getting the desired result.

My data is coming down as an array of objects, which I consider like this:

`data = Team > Days > Games`

The data received is an array containing sports teams and games they may play on a day Mon-Sun (0-6).

I need to transform that data so it's structured as such:

`data = Days > Teams > Games`

Example data:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        team: 'LA Lakers'
        days: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: 'Monday',
                games: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        home: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        home: true
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        home: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            { id: 1, name: 'Tuesday', games:[] },
            { id: 2, name: 'Wednesday', games:[] },
            { id: 3, name: 'Thursday', games:[] },
            { id: 4, name: 'Friday', games:[] },
            { id: 5, name: 'Saturday', games:[] },
            { id: 6, name: 'Sunday', games:[] }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        team: 'NJ Nets'
        days: [
            { id: 0, name: 'Monday', games:[] },
            { id: 1, name: 'Tuesday', games:[] },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Wednesday',
                games: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        home: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        home: true
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        home: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            { id: 3, name: 'Thursday', games:[] },
            { id: 4, name: 'Friday', games:[] },
            { id: 5, name: 'Saturday', games:[] },
            { id: 6, name: 'Sunday', games:[] }
        ]
    },
];
```

My desired result:

```
  var newData = [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Monday',
            teams: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'LA Lakers'
                    games: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            home: false
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            home: true
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            home: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        { id:1, name:'Tuesday', teams:[] },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Wednesday',
            teams: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'NJ Nets'
                    games: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            home: false
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            home: true
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            home: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
    ];
```

I'm able to leverage lodash and was thinking maybe the groupby feature would be useful, or just possible using a for loop to push the info into a new array? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you should add an example of what you've already done to try and do that. its a simple looping excercise

Answer (score 0):

my solution with [lodash 4.17.4](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4)

```
const res = _.chain(data)
    .flatMap('days')
    .uniqBy('id')
    .map(_.partialRight(_.omit, 'games')) // get all days without games
    .map((day) => { // iterate days
        // get teams withs games at this day
        const teamsWithGames = _.chain(data) 
            .filter(team => _.some(team.days, { id: day.id })) // filter teams by day
            .map(_.partialRight(_.omit, 'days')) // delete days from teams
            .map((team) => {
                // assign games at this day to team 
                return _.chain(data)
                    .find({ id: team.id })
                    .get('days')
                    .filter({ id: day.id })
                    .flatMap('games')
                    .thru(games => _.assign({}, team, { games }))
                    .value();
            })
            .filter(team => _.size(team.games) > 0)
            .value();
       return _.assign({}, day, { teams: teamsWithGames }); // return day with teams
    }, [])
    .value();
```